# replace one variable in nested json file

Tags: python, json, csv

I have the following JSON file named as info.Json:

```
{
    "jobs": [
        
        {
            "type": "Account",
            "min": 5,
            "max": 15,
            "arguments": {
                "inix": 48,
                "load": "3.081579e+07",
                "overload": "6.508037e+07"

            },
            "attributes": {
                "name": "emp_1",
                "priority_type": "low",
                "dependency": "-"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "detect",
            "min": 5,
            "max": 13,
            "arguments": {
                "inix": 748,
                "load": "3.081579e+07",
                "overload": "6.508037e+07"

            },
            "attributes": {
                "name": "emp_2",
                "priority_type": "high",
                "dependency": "-"
            }
        },
         {
            "type": "Account",
            "min": 5,
            "max": 15,
            "arguments": {
                "inix": 48,
                "load": "3.081579e+07",
                "overload": "6.508037e+07"

            },
            "attributes": {
                "name": "emp_3",
                "priority_type": "low",
                "dependency": "-"
            }
        }
      
        
    ]
}
```

I have tried to write the following python code, to take a value of dependency from csv file and write it rather than the "-". What I need is just replace each occaurence of "-" with job_dependency value which read from csv file.

```
path='/load/statistics.csv'

for repeat in range(repeats):
        job_statistics = pd.read_csv(path)
        job_dependency = job_statistics['dependency'][repeat]
        print(job_exe_time)
        temp["attributes"]["dependency"]= f"{job_dependency}"

        with open("data_inv_jobs50.json", "wt") as fout:
                for line in file_data:
                         fout.write(line.replace("-","{job_exe_time}"))
```

I need to replace the value of "dependency": "-" with "dependency": "value from csv" , but my code above not working well .. any suggestion ?

Comment: can you give a sample of statistics.csv file, the provided piece of code isn't consistent, what are file_data, temp, repeats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

```py
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Retrieving the dependency value
    value_from_csv = 150
    # Opening the json file
    with open("info.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json_dict = json.load(file)
    # Modifying the json object
    for i in range(len(json_dict["jobs"])):
        json_dict["jobs"][i]["attributes"]["dependency"] = value_from_csv
    # Re-writing the object in a json file
    with open("info2.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(json_dict, file, indent=4)
```

Here I asssumed there was only one dependency value. In this case, you can (and should) retrieve this value first, before entering the loop you will use to modify the content of your file.

Comment: the the output formate of info2.json appears different from the original Json file. I would keep the same formate also the '-' did not replaced

Comment: First, what is the '-' that hasn't been changed? On my end, every attribute "dependency" have been changed. Second, to be fair, the format of a json file doesn't have any impact on its validity. Though I can understand if you need it to be readable. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to replace the '-' value with your desired value.

```
for item in dic['jobs']:
...:     item['attributes']['dependency'] = value_from_csv
```

Comment: how can I reflect this on my file ?

Comment: you can apply it to your json file.